# PHP Pagination for user?

Tags: php

I've tried to make a pagination with PHP, but it seems to not work. I want to limit my data which showing in each page, I have this code and it uses PHP code:

**showUsers.php**

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("select * from users");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>

<td><?php echo $data['no_peg']; ?></td>
<td>
    <?php 
    echo $data['username']; 

    //previlage admin
    if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') {
    ?>
        <div class="row-actions">
        <a href="edit.php?uid=<?php echo $data['id_user'];?>">Edit</a>
        <?php if ($data['role'] != 'admin') {?>
         | <a href="delete.php?uid=<?php echo $data['id_bio'];?>" onClick="return confirm('Hapus akun ini?')" class="delete">Delete</a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $data['fullname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['telephone']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['email']; ?></td>
```

I want to show just 10 names per page, to avoid long scrolling, but how can it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$sqlCount = "select count(id_user) from users";   
$rsCount = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sqlCount));  
$totalData = $rsCount[0];  
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;  
$limit = 10;  
$start_from = $limit * ($page - 1);  
$sql_limit = "SELECT * FROM users limit $start_from, $limit";  
$result = mysql_query($sql_limit);  



        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>

            <td><?php echo $data['no_peg']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                echo $data['username']; 

                //previlage admin
                if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') {
                ?>
                    <div class="row-actions">
                    <a href="edit.php?uid=<?php echo $data['id_user'];?>">Edit</a>
                    <?php if ($data['role'] != 'admin') {?>
                     | <a href="delete.php?uid=<?php echo $data['id_bio'];?>" onClick="return confirm('Hapus akun ini?')" class="delete">Delete</a>
                    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $data['fullname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['telephone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>



        <?php 

        } 
        ?>





<?php
$totalPage = ceil($totalData / $limit);  
echo 'Page : ';  
for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPage; $i++){  
if($page != $i){  
echo '[<a href="showUsers.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>] ';  
}else{  
echo "[$i] ";  
  }  
 }  
?>
```

Comment: Could you 1) format your code properly and more importantly, 2), explain what you've done?

Answer (score 1):

Hi，if you want to make a pagination, you should add in a LIMIT clause into your queries, like this:

```
SELECT* FROM users LIMIT 0, 10
```

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

So, what's the next?

You need to add a parameter to your query url specifies the number of page when you list the users.

Such as:

```
showUsers.php?page=1
```

Then, in your program, you can get parameter by this:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

I hope it will help you, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your pagination code? Your code just shows this query:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from users");
```

But for basic pagination you need to set a `LIMIT` like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from users LIMIT 0,10");
```

So that would only grab the first 10 items. And then—let’s say, on page 2 you could do this:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from users LIMIT 11,10");
```

That would grab the next 10 items starting from item 11.

That’s the basic concept. But you have to code the logic for passing along pagination values & such.

Comment: You would also want to add in a ORDER BY clause into queries that use LIMIT, and preferably order by a field which is a primary key for performance on bigger tables.

Comment: Using OFFSET too might come in handy

Comment: @kimbarcelona, his examples are using LIMIT with the 2 parameters (offset,limit) already, which is the equivalent of using an OFFSET clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(is_int($_GET('pageNo'))) // getting the page number from the URL i.e script.php?pageNo=2
{



            $query = mysql_query("select * from users limit ".$_GET['pageNo']." ,10");

            while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            ?>

            <td><?php echo $data['no_peg']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                echo $data['username']; 

                //previlage admin
                if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') {
                ?>
                    <div class="row-actions">
                    <a href="edit.php?uid=<?php echo $data['id_user'];?>">Edit</a>
                    <?php if ($data['role'] != 'admin') {?>
                     | <a href="delete.php?uid=<?php echo $data['id_bio'];?>" onClick="return confirm('Hapus akun ini?')" class="delete">Delete</a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $data['fullname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['telephone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>



        <?php 

        }
```

} // not sure where the closing if should be you figure it out :P 
            ?>